# Add Title For xamarin.forms Master Page Contain TabbedPage as Details page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I using Master Detail page

The Detail page is an tabbed page

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" ...... >
    <views:InboxPage    Title="" Icon="tabb_inbox.png" />
    <views:AgendaPage    Title="" Icon="tabb_agenda.png"/>
    <views:AttendancePage    Title="" Icon="tabb_attendance.png"/>
    <page:CalendarPage Title="" Icon="tabb_calendar.png" ></page:CalendarPage>
    <views:MarksPage    Title="" Icon="tabb_marks.png"/>
    <!--<views:CalendarPage Title="" Icon="tabb_calendar.png" />-->


</TabbedPage>
```

The Menu(masterpage) is a Content page :

```
     public partial class MasterPageMenu : ContentPage
        {
            public MasterPageMenu()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                InitializeDataAsync();
}
}
```

in the master Page render using the following

```
 public partial class MasterPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
  public MasterPage()
        {
Detail = new NavigationPage(bottomBarPage);

        Master = new MasterPageMenu()
        {
            Title = "The Title ",

            Icon = (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS) ? "icon.png" : null
        };
}
}
```

Is There Any way to display page title beside the menu Icon

[the result for above code like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX0QO.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually pass the title in program code as follow ( when navigating to the page ).

```
new tabbedPafe(){ Title = 'Put title here'};
```

But I think you can also do it in your XAML code if you prefer that (of your tabbed page, give it the Title attribute).

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" ...... Title="Title here">


 <views:InboxPage    Title="" Icon="tabb_inbox.png" />
    <views:AgendaPage    Title="" Icon="tabb_agenda.png"/>
    <views:AttendancePage    Title="" Icon="tabb_attendance.png"/>
    <page:CalendarPage Title="" Icon="tabb_calendar.png" ></page:CalendarPage>
    <views:MarksPage    Title="" Icon="tabb_marks.png"/>
    <!--<views:CalendarPage Title="" Icon="tabb_calendar.png" />-->

</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: Thanks, But when I add Title for tabbed page not displayed beside the menu Icon it displayed in the tabbed navigation under the icon

Comment: Aaah yes I know that bug, I had it before, ima dig in my old project and see if I can find it

Comment: Ooops that's  my fault I expected the title for the navigated page to displayed in the menu , Thanks for your comment solved by adding title as you mentioned